# Highchart in angularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive

I wrap a highchart in a angularJS directive, and I'm trying to add a button that should be display just below the chart.
The problem is the button does not exists.

HTML:

```
<div id="container" my-chart style="height: 400px; margin-top: 1em"></div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('myChart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,

        template: '<div><div id="chart"></div><div><button id="btn">Click</button></div><div>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.highcharts({
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },

                series: [{
                    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                }]

            });
        }
    }
});
```

please see this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cx4dy8y/) for example.

UPDATE:
This is the fixed [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cx4dy8y/2/) after implementing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you are calling .highcharts() on element so it deletes everything inside and renders chart inside. try using template like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div><button id="btn">Click</button></div>
</div>
```

and then in your directive link function call:

```
$("#chart").highcharts({})
```

Instead of this id selector You can use what ever kind of selector you want. You can put class and then call it on element child with class chart like:

```
$(elem).children(".chart").highcharts({...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to add a button in a highcharts way, maybe this fiddle can help you:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/2F4pJ/)

```
exporting: {
        buttons: {
            customButton: {
                x: -62,
                onclick: function () {
                    alert('Clicked');
                },
                symbol: 'circle'
            }
        }
    }
```